# Insert a new row for every change in value in a column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a sql table, in which for every change in a value in a certain column say Column C, I want to insert a new row under it to create a new transaction. I am not sure how to find that value change and insert a new row. I have been doing this through VB code on the csv file I Import into the table but unable to write it in SQL.

```
Sub InsertRows()
  Dim r As Long, mcol As String, i As Long

' find last used cell in Column A
  r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

 ' get value of  last used cell in column A
  mcol = Cells(r, 1).Value

 ' insert rows by looping from bottom
  For i = r To 2 Step -1
     If Cells(i, 1).Value <> mcol Then
       mcol = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Rows(i + 1).Insert
     End If
  Next i

End Sub
```

Here's the sample data

```
ID  JOB FNAME   LNAME   ADDRESS1    ADDRESS2    DATE    Concatenated
1234    A   John    Smith   4378 Anna St    Seattle-WA-98040    12/24/2013  1234-A-41632
1234    A   John    Doe 3564 Lucie Ave  Mercer Island-WA-98040  12/24/2013  1234-A-41632
1235    A   Alex    Smith   4554 Devon Ave  Chicago-IL-60563    12/24/2013  1235-A-41632
1235    A   Eli Manning 5555 Stranz Lane    Dallas-TX-75213 12/24/2013  1235-A-41632
1233    B   John    Smith   4378 Anna St    Seattle-WA-98040    12/24/2013  1233-B-41632
1233    C   John    Doe 3564 Lucie Ave  Mercer Island-WA-98040  12/24/2013  1233-C-41632
1236    D   Alex    Smith   4554 Devon Ave  Chicago-IL-60563    12/24/2013  1236-D-41632
1236    E   Eli Manning 5555 Stranz Lane    Dallas-TX-75213 12/24/2013  1236-E-41632
```

Below is the desired output

```
ID  JOB FNAME   LNAME   ADDRESS1    ADDRESS2    DATE    Concatenated
1234    A   John    Smith   4378 Anna St    Seattle-WA-98040    12/24/2013  1234-A-41632
1234    A   John    Doe 3564 Lucie Ave  Mercer Island-WA-98040  12/24/2013  1234-A-41632

1235    A   Alex    Smith   4554 Devon Ave  Chicago-IL-60563    12/24/2013  1235-A-41632
1235    A   Eli Manning 5555 Stranz Lane    Dallas-TX-75213 12/24/2013  1235-A-41632

1233    B   John    Smith   4378 Anna St    Seattle-WA-98040    12/24/2013  1233-B-41632

1237    C   John    Doe 3564 Lucie Ave  Mercer Island-WA-98040  12/24/2013  1237-C-41632

1236    D   Alex    Smith   4554 Devon Ave  Chicago-IL-60563    12/24/2013  1236-D-41632

1236    E   Eli Manning 5555 Stranz Lane    Dallas-TX-75213 12/24/2013  1236-E-41632
```

The column "concatenated" is where i'm trying to find a change and insert a row after every change.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a "csv" file, how do you intend to run SQL on it?  Can you give the layout of the data in the database, along with sample data and desired results?

Comment: to catch data changes in SQL (TSQL too) it are used `sql triggers`, but i don't see how they are related to you problem since you are working on CSV

Comment: Sorry I import that csv file into sql, i am editing my question and posting a sample file with desired result as well.

Answer (score 0):

you really want to write a stored procedure run either from you data source into you database or time depended in your database.

here is the code

BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE Test_table ADD COLUMN b1(10,2);

UPDATE test_table SET romney_pct = CAST (romney AS DECIMAL (10,2)) / CAST (uspres_total AS DECIMAL (10,2);

COMMIT;